# JBoss cache. Concurrency issue

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-cache

I'm using *JBossCache 'Malagueta' 3.2.0.GA*

I faced with strange issue in production environment, sometimes writes to jboss cache do not work properly. I tried to reproduce this situation with simple java application

```
public static void testCache() {
    Cache cache = new DefaultCacheFactory().createCache(false);
    cache.create();
    cache.start();
    final Node node = cache.getRoot().addChild(Fqn.fromString("/child1"));
    int threadsCount = 20;
    final CyclicBarrier b = new CyclicBarrier(threadsCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++) {
        final long j = i;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    b.await();
                    String name = RandomGenerator.getRandomName(4);
                    node.put(j, name);
                    String nameFromCache = (String) node.get(j);
                    if (!name.equals(nameFromCache)) {
                        System.out.println("error");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

From time to time, this test output "error", which i run from `static void main` fail. 1 of 3 runs return "error" msg. It simply return null. I can't reproduce it on every machine.

Any clue ?

Comment: May be you need lock node before accessing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to cache 3.2.5 solved this problem. Seems like it's  [jboss cache bug](http://community.jboss.org/message/271386).

Answer (score 2):

You code looks fine so it may be that the Jboss cache is asynchronous.  I see nothing in the Javadocs that guarantees when the cache would be updated.

I know in many distributed cache implementations, a `put` operation is written out to the wire and even the local instance of the cache is updated from the inbound message, not directly through a local call.  This allows caches to appropriately serialize their updates so that updates from multiple machines are processed in the correct order on all nodes in the network.

One thing to try is to set the cache to be LOCAL.  Something like the following:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setCacheMode(LOCAL);
Cache cache = new DefaultCacheFactory().createCache(config, false);
...
```

If that does not fail then I suspect I am correct.  Even if it does still fail I may be correct since the `LOCAL` modes may still have a loopback network stack underneath or something.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By default cache is run in local mode, seems it's jboss cache bug.

Comment: Another thing to try is to put a spin loop into each one of the threads and see how long it takes for the null responses to go away.